# How to get the total number and lastest commit of project in github using Api

Tags: github, github-api

Actually, I have two ideas to get total number of commits,

One idea is to using api like:`https://api.github.com/repos/mojombo/grit/commits`, this way can get all commits and we can count it to get the total number and the lasted date of commit. But the main problem is that there are too many commits it would be slower.

The other idea is that since I already got the statics of contributors using api `https://api.github.com/repos/mojombo/grit/contributors` , and the total number of contributor is the same with what I see in the [grit website](https://github.com/mojombo/grit), and I from this api call, I also get the contributions of each contributor, then I sum contributions of all contributors, it should the same value with the website, but unfortunately, it is different from 513. The code is following and May I know why there is difference?

```
import json, requests
all_contributors = list()
page_count = 1
total_contributions=0
while True:
    contributors = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/mojombo/grit/contributors?page=%d"%page_count)
    if contributors != None and contributors.status_code == 200 and len(contributors.json()) > 0:
        all_contributors = all_contributors + contributors.json()
    else:
        break
    page_count = page_count + 1
total_contributor=len(all_contributors)
for contr in all_contributors:
    total_contributions=total_contributions+contr['contributions']
print("--------total contributor-----------%d" %total_contributor) //print 43
print("--------total commits-----------%d" %total_contributions) //print 497
```

Thanks

Comment: I already know how to get the latest commits :)

Answer (score 2):

I feel you are missing some anonymous commits. To include anonymous contributors, you can change your code to -                                                                        `contributors = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/mojombo/grit/contributors?anon=1&page=%d"%page_count)`